# Calculating redshift from distant galaxies using spacetime metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, galaxies, doppler-effect

In Sean Carroll's GR book, pg. 104, it was said that at a rigorous level, the notion that galaxies are "receding away from us" at a speed defined by their redshift is nonsense, since velocities at different points on a curved spacetime manifold lie in different tangent spaces and cannot be compared in a natural way.

Instead of using the conventional Doppler effect to describe the redshift of distant galaxies, what is actually happening is that the spacetime between us and the galaxies has changed (universe has expanded), leading to an increase in the wavelength of the light.

Mathematically, how do we use the spacetime metric to calculate the redshift of distant galaxies?

Comment: It is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Expansion_of_space

Comment: @safesphere thanks, very useful!